# bubble sorting switch and rotate challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am trying to create a class MarblesBoard also include switch and rotate function.

My code is below:

```
class MarblesBoard():
def __init__(self, balls):
    self.balls = balls
def __repr__(self):
    return " ".join(str(i) for i in self.balls)

def switch(self):
    lst=list(self.balls)
    lst[0], lst[1] = lst[1], lst[0]        
    return lst

def rotate(self): 
    lst=list(self.balls)
    lst = lst[1:]+lst[:1]
    return self.balls
```

The out put should be like:

```
>>> board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5)) 
>>> board 
3 6 7 4 1 0 8 2 5 
>>> board.switch() 
>>> board 
6 3 7 4 1 0 8 2 5 
>>> board.rotate() 
>>> board 
3 7 4 1 0 8 2 5 6 
>>> board.switch() 
>>> board 
7 3 4 1 0 8 2 5 6
```

However, when I use switch or rotate, it allays call the original ball list. Not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually modifying `self.balls`, just returning a modified list.

If you want to keep your methods basically the same, and continue to work with tuples, you could change the definition of `switch()` to actually write the changes to `self.balls` by doing something like:

```
  def switch(self):
      lst=list(self.balls)
      lst[0], lst[1] = lst[1], lst[0]  
      self.balls = tuple(lst)
```

Likewise, you can change `rotate()` to something like this:

```
  def rotate(self): 
      lst=list(self.balls)
      lst = lst[1:]+lst[:1]
      self.balls=tuple(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are returning lists. If you want to modify the object, you have to change `self.balls` instead of `return`ing. Like this:

```python
class MarblesBoard:

    def __init__(self, balls):
        self.balls = balls

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(str(i) for i in self.balls)

    def switch(self):
        self.balls[0], self.balls[1] = self.balls[1], self.balls[0]

    def rotate(self):
        self.balls = self.balls[1:] + self.balls[:1]
```

Comment: Thanks Nog642, however, I got the error TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Yes, if `self.balls` starts out as a tuple then the `switch` method I wrote wouldn't work, since as the error says, you can't assign to a tuple index. In that case, you could implement it the exact same way you implemented it in the question except replace the last line `return lst` with `self.balls = tuple(list)`.